# k-form decomposition on MxR

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

My question arises from "An Introduction To Manifolds" 2nd edition P313

quote begin

Let $\omega_\alpha$ be a k-form on $M\times R$ and $(U_\alpha, x^1, ..., x^n)$ is a local chart on $M$, then $\omega_\alpha$ can be written as:

$\omega_\alpha = \sum_I a_Idx^I + \sum_J b_Jdt\wedge dx^J$

quote end

The decomposition is directly used without proof. How to understand the decomposition? I think $dx^I$ is a k-1 form, but $dt\wedge dx^J$ is a k-form. How can a k-form $\omega_\alpha$ be decomposed as sum of k-forms and k-1 forms? And how to determine the coefficients $a_I$ and $b_J$?

Comment: $dx^I$ is meant to be a $k$-form. This decomposition isn't anything more than "write down what forms are in local coordinates, except call $dx^{n+1}$ $dt$ instead."

Comment: Understand. I think I complicate the matter. Thanks.